# CSS floats funky

Tags: html, css

My floats are acting strange (well I guess they're acting how they're supposed to), but I can't seem to understand why. For some reason the div box that contains 'Alex' always goes down to another line. Is there something I'm messing up?

style.css

```
.clear {
    clear:both;
}
.page-header {
    width:100%;
    background:#efefef;
    border-bottom:1px #ddd solid;
    padding:3px 10px;
    margin-bottom:24px;
}
.page-header-title {
    width:200px;
    float:none;
}
.page-header-search {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
} 
.page-header-top_menu {
    float:right;
    width:200px;
}
```

index.html

```
<div class="page-header">
        <div class="page-header-search">
            blah
        </div>

        <div class="page-header-title">
            Calender
        </div>

        <div class="page-header-top_menu">
            Alex
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: `page-header-title` is not floated, but works when you float it also. EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/F72zJ/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you exchange the

```
float: none;
```

for the "calender"-div with

```
float: left;
```

the "Alex" behaves better.

You didn't specify how it should look like.

http://jsfiddle.net/wDp3p/ << I visualized your div-structure with red borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/wDp3p/1/ << version with float: left;

"float" is not really for solutions like table columns but for floating - so the "calender"-div floats directly after its left hand previous element.

Answer (score 0):

You're floating it wrongly. You should assign a `float` property to `.page-header-title`.